# What is a word for "someone to whom you pledge loyalty"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that behaves almost like an antonym for "follower" or "constituent", but that doesn't carry the "official-ness" of "leader."

> He felt betrayed by his [person to whom he pledged loyalty]

Answer (score 1):

He felt betrayed by his [**liege**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/liege). This is a somewhat medieval in tone.  However, in modern times it would be unusual to pledge loyalty to anyone less than a sovereign in a Constitutional Monarchy.

Comment: Sadly though, and very important to note, **both** sides use the noun *liege* -- ibid.